# SpotifyWebApi - Trouble with authentication (Authorization Code) in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, spotify

Im trying to develop a simple application using the spotify API but i can't get Authentication to work. In the frontend, i have a button that sends a call to /authorize which looks like this:

```
var CLIENT_ID = 'blabla'; // Your client id
var CLIENT_SECRET = 'blablabla'; // Your secret
var REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:4001/logincallback';
const STATE_KEY = "spotify_auth_state";
const scopes = ['user-read-private', 'user-read-email'];

const spotifyApi = new Spotify({
  clientId: CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
  redirectUri: REDIRECT_URI
});

/**
 * The /login endpoint
 * Redirect the client to the spotify authorize url, but first set that user's
 * state in the cookie.
 */
const generateRandomString = N => (Math.random().toString(36)+Array(N).join('0')).slice(2, N+2);

router.get('/', (_, res) => {
  const state = generateRandomString(16);
  res.cookie(STATE_KEY, state);
  var authorized_url = spotifyApi.createAuthorizeURL(scopes, state);
  res.redirect(authorized_url);
});

module.exports = router;
```

And then in /logincallback i have

```
var CLIENT_ID = 'blabla'; // Your client id
var CLIENT_SECRET = 'blabla'; // Your secret


router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const { code, state } = req.query;
  const storedState = req.cookies ? req.cookies[STATE_KEY] : null;
  // first do state validation
  if (state === null || state !== storedState) {
    res.redirect('/#/error/state mismatch');
    console.log("Incorrect state");
  // if the state is valid, get the authorization code and pass it on to the client
  } else {
    res.clearCookie(STATE_KEY);
    // Retrieve an access token and a refresh token
    spotifyApi.authorizationCodeGrant(code).then(data => {
      const { expires_in, access_token, refresh_token } = data.body;
      // Set the access token on the API object to use it in later calls
      spotifyApi.setAccessToken(access_token);
      spotifyApi.setRefreshToken(refresh_token);

      // use the access token to access the Spotify Web API
      spotifyApi.getMe().then(({ body }) => {
        console.log(body);
      });

      // we can also pass the token to the browser to make requests from there
      res.redirect(`/#/user/${access_token}/${refresh_token}`);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.redirect('/#/error/invalid token');
    });
  }
});
```

This is all copied straight from the Spotify API examples. However, the call to res.redirect(authorized_url) doesn't seem to fire - as in, i get a request to /authorize but no subsequent request to /logincallback. If i do res.redirect('/logincallback'), the API responds with a Bad Request. I used Postman to send a request without any params directly to /logincallback, but that obviously fails as it's missing the information provided from the first call to the spotify API. A Postman request to /authorize gives me a I've added these routes to the whitelist in the developer dashboard:

```
https://localhost:4001/logincallback/ 
http://localhost:4001/logincallback/ 
https://localhost:4001/logincallback
http://localhost:4001/logincallback 
https://localhost:4001/
```

**SHORT VERSION:** Call to spotify API using spotifyApi.createAuthorizeURL doesn't fire

Comment: Can you log `spotifyApi` and does it show an object with the method `createAuthorizeURL`? Also if you wrap `spotifyApi.createAuthorizeURL()` in a try catch, does it throw an error?

Comment: console.log on spotifyApi gives me the following{ _credentials: 
   { clientId: 'blabla',
     clientSecret: 'blablabla,
     redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4001/logincallback' } }, and wrapping createURL in a try/catch does not throw an error

Comment: I just remembered that if you log a class in node, it will only show you the classes attributes and wont show it's methods. Can you console log `spotifyApi.createAuthorizeURL`?

Comment: That gives me [Function: createAuthorizeURL]

Comment: Ok great, so that confirms the class is set up correctly. Did you try wrapping the function call in a try / catch? Did it throw an error at all?

Comment: Yeah i tried that, doesn't throw an error

Answer (score 0):

Registering `http://localhost:4001/logincallback` as the callback API on spotify does not work as the spotify servers do not know where to route the request to.
The way I made it work was to deploy my app on heroku (i.e. get a public endpoint) and the register the callback to that.